# The $C_0-$group generated by the operator $(Af)(x)=f'(x)+a(x)f(x)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, closed-form, semigroup-of-operators

Consider the Banach space $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ of integrable functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$. Consider the unbounded operator $A$ defined by
$$(Af)(x)=f'(x)+a(x)f(x), \ \ \ x\in \mathbb{R}$$
for each absolutely continuous function $f$  such that $f'\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, where $a:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a bounded function.

I wonder whether the $C_0-group$ generated by $A$ has the following explicit form
$$(T(t)f)(x)=e^{a(x)t}f(t+x),\ \ \ \ \ t\in \mathbb{R}, \ \ \ x\in \mathbb{R}.$$
I am also interested in the case the function $a(.)$ is not bounded.

Comment: Does $T(t')T(t)f = T(t'+t)f$? Have you checked this? It doesn't appear to me that this is true.

Comment: @T.A.E. Why not? user170243: Why do you not calculate the generator of $(T_t)$? Then you'll see whether it equals $A$.

Comment: @saz : $T(t')T(t)f = T(t')[e^{ta(x)}f(x+t)]=e^{t'a(x)}[e^{ta(x+t')}f(x+t'+t)]$. $T(t'+t)f = e^{(t+t')a(x)}f(x+t'+t)$. If it's not a group, then it cannot be the group generated by anything.

Comment: @T.A.E. Ah, damn, forgot about the $x$-dependence in the exponent. You are right, thanks.

Comment: @T.A.E. Ah yes, thanks, this is not a $C_0-$group. Maybe $(T(t)f)(x)=e^{\int_x^{x+t}a(y)dy}f(x+t)$ is what I am looking for. But I don't know if its generator is exactly $A$ or another operator.

Comment: I think $(T(t)f)(x)=e^{\int_t^{x+t}a(y)dy}f(x+t)$ generates the operator $A$: $$|\frac{T(t)f-f}{t}-Af|\leq \int exp(\int_x^{x+t}a(y)dy).|\frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t}-f'(x)|+\int|\frac{exp(\int_x^{x+t}a(y)dy)-1}{t}-a(x)|.|f'(x)|+\int|exp(\int_x^{x+t}a(y)dy)-1|.|f'(x)|$$ The other family $(S(t)f)(x)=e^{a(x)t}f(x+t)$ also satisfies $|\frac{S(t)f-f}{t}-Af|\to 0$ as $t\to 0$. I thought something was wrong, but I think its fine because $S(t)$ is not a group as T.A.E. mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator $Af=(\frac{d}{dx}+a)f$ is, in a classical sense, similar to the differentiation operator because
$$
    Af = e^{-\int a(x)dx}\frac{d}{dx}e^{\int a(x)dx}f = M^{-1}\frac{d}{dx}Mf.
$$
Because of this, any function of the operator $A$ is a corresponding function of $\frac{d}{dx}$. In particular,
$$
            e^{tA}f = e^{-\int a(x)dx}e^{t\frac{d}{dx}}e^{\int a(x)dx}f
$$
Without regard to rigor (at least for the moment,) and assuming a Taylor series expansion for $g$,
$$
   e^{t\frac{d}{dx}}g = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{n}g^{(n)}(x)}{n!} = g(x+t).
$$
That's enough to suggest the form of the group, if there is one:
$$
\begin{align}
     (T(t)f)(x) & = e^{-\int_{0}^{x}a(y)dy}(e^{\int_{0}^{x+t}a(y)dy}f(x+t)) \\
                & = e^{\int_{x}^{x+t}a(y)dy}f(x+t).
\end{align}
$$
**Check the Answer:** The above formula for $T(t)$ seems to work; I'll let you work out the group property. As for the the generator ...
$$
    \frac{d}{dt} T(t)f = \frac{d}{dt}\left[e^{\int_{x}^{x+t}a(y)dy}f(x+t)\right]\\
   = e^{\int_{x}^{x+t}a(y)dy}f'(x+t)+e^{\int_{x}^{x+t}a(y)dy}a(x+t)f(x+t).
$$
Setting $t=0$ gives
$$
                \frac{d}{dt}T(t)f|_{t=0} = f'(x)+a(x)f(x).
$$
Of course, that's not a fully rigorous proof of the generator because you must carry out the calculation in the norm of $L^{1}$, but I'll leave it to you for the case where $f,f' \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$.

The expression for $T(t)$ defines a bounded operator on $L^{1}$; if $a$ is uniformly bounded by $M$, then you have the uniform bound $|\int_{x}^{x+t}a(y)dy| \le Mt$. Hence, $T(t)f \in L^{1}$ if $f\in L^{1}$, and
$$
            |(T(t)f)(x)| \le e^{tM}|f(x+t)|, \\
                  \|T(t)f\|_{L^{1}} \le e^{tM}\|f\|_{L^{1}}.
$$
The $C^{0}$ property for $T$ is easy to verify:
$$
\begin{align}
          \|T(t)f-f\|_{L^{1}}
 & =\left|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\int_{x}^{x+t}a(y)dy}f(x+t)-f(x)dx\right| \\
 & =\left|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(e^{\int_{x-t}^{x}a(y)dy}-1)f(x)dx\right| \\
 & \le \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|e^{\int_{x-t}^{x}a(y)dy}-1||f(x)|dx.
\end{align}
$$
The right side tends to $0$ as $t\rightarrow 0$ by the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just find that translation $C_0-$groups are really weird compared to $C_0-$groups generated by multiplication operators.